# Calling select on change event div load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a script that loads a set of form controls based off of the selection made in a drop-down list. I load the elements from a php file in to a `div` using the following code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#prompt_type').change(function() {
        switch ($( this ).find(":selected").text()) {           
            case 'Select': 
                $('#prompt_elements').load('index.php?path=promptelm&and_id=' + <?php echo $and->and_id; ?> + ' #type_select');
                break;                              
            case 'Radio':
                $('#prompt_elements').load('index.php?path=promptelm&and_id=' + <?php echo $and->and_id; ?> + ' #type_radio');          
                break;
            case 'Checkbox':
```

This part works great. My issue however is I am saving this information to a database and when I revisit the form even though my drop-down contains the correct value the elements are not loading unless I reselect the option to spark the `.change` event again. Is there a way to call my switch right after the drop-down is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your switch in a seperated function, something like:

```
function loadingFunc(jqObj){

      switch ($( jqObj ).find(":selected").text()) {           
            case 'Select': 
               .....
}

$(document).ready(function () {
     loadingFunc( $('#prompt_type'));
     $('#prompt_type').change(function() {
         loadingFunc( $(this));
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try having the change handler in a separate function which will be called on document ready event (depends on your deserialization).